# Trying to insert data into SQL database. Error 1046 No Database Selected

Tags: python, mysql

I have some data in a tab-delimited file that i'm trying to insert into an SQL database. Here is my code

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

new_db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='me')
cursor = new_db.cursor()

cursor.execute('create database if not exists my_database')

maketablestr = """CREATE TABLE info (Disease VARCHAR(10), NCBI Acc. Number VARCHAR(10) ,Length VARCHAR(10), Sequence VARCHAR(10));"""

cursor.execute(maketablestr)
new_db.commit()

tsv_read = csv.reader(file('marfan.tsv'), delimiter = '\t')

for row in tsv_read:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO info(Disease, NCBI Acc. Number, Length, Sequence ) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row)


new_db.commit()
cursor.close()
new_db.close()
print("Database updated")
```

When I run the code, it gives me the error 1046 'No Database Selected'. I'm a little confused as to why I'm getting this error since the code that I wrote is mostly taken from others who are trying to do the same thing as me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this:

1. You run `cursor.execute('use my_database;')`
2. Or you adapt your SQL statements to specify the DB like:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO my_database.info(Disease, NCBI Acc. Number, Length, Sequence ) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', row)
```

Note, with the later approach you need to adapt **all** sql statements

Comment: What would be the syntax for specifying the database when I do cursor.execute(maketablestr)?

Comment: I believe it would be `"""CREATE TABLE my_database.info (Disease VARCHAR(10), NCBI Acc. Number VARCHAR(10) ,Length VARCHAR(10), Sequence VARCHAR(10));"""` but I'm not a mysql expert

Comment: Thank you, you helped me solve one issue, but now I have a SQL syntax error somewhere. I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Happy to hear that: I'm not sure with the second statement: shouldn't you use `%` to specify the start of the python variables rather than `,`. Also you probably need to surround the inserted variables like this `'%s'` and then the entire string by `"..."` rather then `'...'`. In general, you should look into using `.format()` rather then the `"%s" % my_var` notation. And finally, use the mysql console for your debugging, it can make things easier, particularly check if the CREATE statement is correct, success :)